# GCP Managed Notebook doesn't appear under VM instances list, but User Managed Notebooks do - Why?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Apologies, fairly basic question but does anyone know why a managed notebook doesn't appear under then VM instances list? Screenshots attached.

[image: All Instances listed in VM Instance, excluding user managed notebook]

[image: user managed workbook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because as its name says, it is managed by GCP.

This is well explained in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/introduction#google-managed_compute_infrastructure).

> A Vertex AI Workbench managed notebooks instance is a Google-managed, Jupyter notebook-based, compute infrastructure.
>
> When you create a managed notebooks instance, it is deployed as a Google-managed virtual machine (VM) instance in a tenant project.

I'd suggest to check the docs first next time.

Comment: Do you know why the managed instance can't connect to my Cloud SQL database when run on a schedule, but CAN connect when I manually start the instance?

Comment: This is a new question so you may need to create another post.